# Increasing the size of regions on jVectorMap

Tags: jquery, svg, jvectormap

I'm trying to have to display a 2x or 3x version of a region when it is in hover state or selected.

The effect I am going for is to have the selected country "pop out" from the rest of the map and eventually maybe display information particular to the selected region.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find how to do it?